# JOIN a subquery with another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

In my MySQL database I have two tables: `investments` (with a `currency_id` and the `date` of investment) and `currencies` (with data like name, etc).

I would like to select the minimum `date` for each currency inside investments table and then join this result with `currencies`.

The query I imagined would work may make this clearer:

```
SELECT T.currency_id, T.mindate
FROM (
    SELECT * , MIN( DATE ) AS mindate
    FROM investments
    GROUP BY investments.currency_id
    ORDER BY mindate ASC
) AS T
JOIN currencies ON T.currency_id = 
currencies.currency_id
```

However, all I get is the subquery result, and nothing from currencies table is joined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any time you find yourself using `SELECT *` in conjunction with an aggregate, you can be certain that something has gone wrong. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SELECT` clause, you forget to get `currencies` columns' values.
Add `currencies.*` at the first line.

```
SELECT T.currency_id, T.mindate, currencies.*
FROM (
    SELECT * , MIN( DATE ) AS mindate
    FROM investments
    GROUP BY investments.currency_id
    ORDER BY mindate ASC
) AS T
JOIN currencies ON T.currency_id = 
currencies.currency_id
```

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**However** you forgot to select the column[s] from currencies but still it would may not give you the desired output because in the subquery you are selecting all the columns and grouping by only `currency_id`. the query may not run or group by all the rest of columns where group function is not added so you may get unexpected results. So, I would like to suggest the following way instead

```
SELECT T.currency_id, T.mindate, u.currency_name
FROM (
    SELECT currency_id, MIN(DATE) AS mindate
    FROM investments
    GROUP BY investments.currency_id) AS T
JOIN currencies u ON u.currency_id = t.currency_id
```